# VB6 Error Variable Not Defined Related to AeroSuite Component

Tags: components, vb6, controls

I have a VB6 project that I copy from another computer.

I have installed and checked the Reference and Components that the project needed. But there is an error that I can't solve about Aero. It says that AeroTab1 variable is not defined:

[image]

I already put the AeroSuite.oca from another computer in the same directory as the AeroSuite.ocx (windows/System32).

Comment: You don't need the OCA files https://stackoverflow.com/q/4050078/3195477

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought that .oca file is need alongside the .ocx file

Comment: It will get recreated by Windows automatically when it is needed.

Answer (score 3):

That error is indicating that there is no `AeroTab1` control defined on `MainForm`. Take a look at the form in Design mode and see if it is missing a control. If it exists, the name is probably not `AeroTab1`.

When you first moved the project over, if you opened it without having AeroSuite registered, you would've been warned about the missing components. In that scenario, Visual Basic usually replaces the control with a PictureBox. It would still be named AeroTab1 though and you would get errors about properties not being found. Perhaps the PictureBox was removed after installing the missing components.

You should be able to simply create a new AeroTab control on `MainForm`, name it `AeroTab1` and move past this problem.

Comment: To add to that: in case the missing control was replaced by a picturebox by VB6, it also generates a log file name <FormFile>.log, i.e. _ MainForm.log_ in the same directory as the form itself that lists the missing control type(s).